# Domain Forwarding for specific URLs

Tags: redirect, joomla, dns, forwarding

I have a domain with GoDaddy called "livingmiracles.org". For years I had this domain forwarding to my livingmiraclescenter.org Joomla website. Recently, I discovered that the way the livingmiracles.org domain now forwards to our livingmiraclescenter.org site has changed and has left me with broken links on almost all of the over 60 websites I manage.

This is what used to happen:
Any URL of the livingmiraclescenter.org website would be able to be displayed with the livingmiracles.org domain instead. For example, the following URLs were interchangeable:

- livingmiraclescenter.org/david-hoffmeister.html and
  livingmiracles.org/david-hoffmeister.html
- livingmiraclescenter.org/contact.html and
  livingmiracles.org/contact.html
- livingmiraclescenter.org/spiri-tv.html and
  livingmiracles.org/spiri-tv.html

Also, variations of the above without ".html" would work.

Now, none of this works anymore. For the "livingmiracles.org/" links above, now, either the livingmiraclescenter.org home page pulls up or I get a GoDaddy error page.

I called GoDaddy and they confirmed a change in the way they handle domain forwarding now.

Can anyone suggest a simple/smart way—perhaps a RewriteRule or something like that—that I can set up somewhere (where?) to handle those specific page redirects? Basically, I want all my livingmiraclescenter.org links to be interchangeable with livingmiracles.org links like I wrote above in those examples.

Thank you so much!
Jutta

Comment: Maybe instead of formwarding from godaddy, you can change the name servers from the other domain, like https://support.hostgator.com/articles/how-to-change-godaddy-name-servers

Comment: Godaddy used to allow for forwarding but changed awhile ago.  As a duct tape fixed, I had to point my domain to a hosting account I had (changing the nameservers like @Hackerman mentioned) and then put a htaccess there for the wildcard redirects

Comment: Thank you both! @YellowWebMonkey, that's interesting. Would you be open to showing me what you did in the htaccess for wildcard redirects? And, if you only point the domain away from GoDaddy to another hosting account, where do you have that htaccess file located?